# Laravel - Can't run project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

A friend send me a project but it is give me an error when i try run.

I go to project location and execute `php artisan serve` but i have this error:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/project1/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /project1/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

When i run `composer install` i have this error:

```
[ErrorException]
  file_put_contents(/project1/rev2/bootstrap/cache/ser
  vices.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

What is the problem?

Thank you

Comment: did you composer install everything

Comment: I assume you don't have the same filepath as your friend, this might cause an file not found error.

Comment: run `composer install` first before `php artisan serve`

Comment: When i run composer install i had this error. 
file_put_contents(/project1/rev2/bootstrap/cache/services.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory @SteD

Answer (score 1):

Do you compose installed ? if not you can install it form here.
https://getcomposer.org/

Once composer is installed then you can run `php artisan serve` or you can place the project in the wamp/xampp project directory and run like this.

http://localhost/projectname/public

Comment: I have composer installed. I create and run this project, i send it and when i receive it back i can't run. @AsimShahzad

Comment: Ok,what are the errors in the log,you can check that log in /storage/logs/laravel.log file

Comment: I don't receive the storage folder from the sender. @AsimShahzad

Comment: But can i copy from first project version? I try this but doesn't work. @AsimShahzad

Comment: give error on bootstrap/cache/services.php ... i don't have the folder cache/ and file services.php .
There is any way to generate that?

Comment: Alright,which version are you using,you need to install that version first and then copy its storage directory to your project.

Comment: Solved! I create cache folder and run composer install and works. Thank you @AsimShazad

Comment: glad you fixed it,please vote and accept my answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `/project1/rev2/bootstrap/cache` directory in your project location if not, you have to manually create it.